# I need to map this array and output the "level" difference of the last seven days against the current date

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let me try to make the output clearer. This array contains the levels obtained/lost by a character and the dates being the actual dates where the levels were obtained or lost. I want to output the levels obtained/lost in the last seven days (compared to the current date).

Array example:

```
"array": [{
  "date": "2019-12-19 15:53:21",
  "level": "365"
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-20 04:18:24",
  "level": "366"
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-30 06:57:15",
  "level": "370"
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-30 22:19:30",
  "level": "371"
}, {
  "date": "2020-01-02 05:45:14",
  "level": "369"
}, {
  "date": "2020-01-02 09:55:15",
  "level": "370"
}, {
  "date": "2020-01-02 18:42:11",
  "level": "367"
}, {
  "date": "2020-01-03 05:15:08",
  "level": "368"
}]
```

Comment: The current date (2021-08-30) isn't anywhere in the array. Do you mean the last date in the array? Use `array.slice()` to get the previous 7 elements, and `array.map()` to iterate over them and subtract.

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what Otávio is looking for and is what I outlined in my solution.

Comment: Let me try to make the output clearer. This array contains the levels obtained/lost by a character and the dates being the actual dates where the levels were obtained or lost. I want to output the levels obtained/lost in the last seven days (compared to the current date).

Comment: @OtávioC. please see my revised solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the difference in `level` values for the most recent and least recent rows of data within the past seven days of data, using this data provided…

```js
{
  array: [
    { date:"2021-08-17 03:02:02", level: "407" },
    { date:"2021-08-23 05:34:03", level: "408" },
    { date:"2021-08-26 03:46:03", level: "409" },
    { date:"2021-08-27 23:08:14", level: "410" },
    { date:"2021-08-30 23:05:03", level: "411" }
  ]
}
```

…these are steps you can take to filter the array to only those in the past seven days and then evaluate the difference in `level` values between the most and least recent entries:

1. In the `getLevelDiff` function, I compare the date of each row of data to the current date and temporarily store the difference in number of days in a property I called `diff`.
2. I then filter rows with dates aged seven or more days ago.
3. Next, I sort the rows by their difference in days.
4. Finally, I subtract the level of the oldest filtered row by date from the level of the most recent date and return that value on the following line of the function.

Here this is in action:

```js
const data = {
  array: [
    { date:"2021-08-17 03:02:02", level: "407" },
    { date:"2021-08-23 05:34:03", level: "408" },
    { date:"2021-08-26 03:46:03", level: "409" },
    { date:"2021-08-27 23:08:14", level: "410" },
    { date:"2021-08-30 23:05:03", level: "411" }
  ]
};
const today = new Date();
const getLevelDiff = arr => {
  const compared = arr.map(row => ({...row, diff: (today - new Date(row.date)) / 8.64e+7})),
        filtered = compared.filter(row => row.diff < 7),
        sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff),
        diff = sorted.length ? +sorted[0].level - +sorted[sorted.length - 1].level : null;
  return diff;
}
console.log('The level difference is ' + getLevelDiff(data.array));
```

Some points worth mentioning—

- In my date comparison, I check for any dates occurring in the past seven days, ranging between the current date (`0` days ago) and `7` days ago. Once a date is at least 7 days past, it is older than a week and is thus filtered out. If you would like to include that seventh day previous and its values, switch the `7` to an `8` to be inclusive of entries from 7 days ago.
- It is also worth mentioning that these are datetime comparisons, so a row of data from 7 days ago **before** the current time of day would be considered more than 7 days old and thus filtered out, whereas a row of data from 7 days ago **after** the current time of day would be considered less than 7 days old, so it would be retained. If you would like to compare only by date, independent of time, I can adjust my function to only compare by date by ignoring the time component of the `date` properties when comparing, and only compare to today's date rather than the current datetime. Please let me know if you would like me to make this adjustment.
- I opted to use the unary `+` operator convert the `level` strings to numbers, but you could use `Number()` or `parseInt()` if you prefer.
- In this line, I also perform a ternary check to ensure there is at least one row of data to prevent any errors from occurring. If there are no rows of data that match the filter, the function returns `null`.
- With the previous point in mind, if there is only one row, the function will return `0` as the first and last elements in the filtered array are the same and thus have the same `level` value. If you would instead like to return `null` is there are fewer than 2 array elements to compare, simply switch my `sorted.length` check to `sorted.length > 1` (greater than 1, at least 2).
- Depending on how the levels work, if the most recent date were to have a `level` value less than that of the least recent date, the function, as is, would return a negative value (e.g. `-1`). If you would always like to return the `level` value difference as a positive number, simply wrap the return value in `Math.abs()` to return the absolute (positive) value of the resultant value, like this: `Math.abs(diff)`.

Comment: Let me try to make the output clearer. This array contains the levels obtained/lost by a character and the dates being the actual dates where the levels were obtained or lost. I want to output the levels obtained/lost in the last seven days (compared to the current date).

Comment: @OtávioC. so if I understand correctly, you want to return the same array, filtered to include only those entries that happened in the past seven days (compared to the current date). Is that correct? How can I test this using the sample data you provided, as the most recent date in that array happened over a year ago?

Comment: Yes, filter the entries that happened in the past seven days (compared to the current date) and then return the difference in "levels" between the most recent date in the array and the oldest one (seventh day?). Would this array provide the needed information? "array":[{"date":"2021-08-17 03:02:02","level":"407"},{"date":"2021-08-23 05:34:03","level":"408"},{"date":"2021-08-26 03:46:03","level":"409"},{"date":"2021-08-27 23:08:14","level":"410"},{"date":"2021-08-30 23:05:03","level":"411"}]

Comment: @OtávioC. yes, that does help to clarify. Please see my revised solution.

Comment: Yes, this is it. I really appreciate the help Brandon. Sorry for not being clear enough initially with the expected output.

Comment: @OtávioC. no worries at all. If my solution answered your question, would you mind selecting it as the accepted answer? Thanks :)